# wait for function execution before executing next instruction

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous

I'm trying to upload images to firebase and get the download Url and save the url in the firestore in the database. The code was working until I modified it to handle multiple images. To handle multiple images I have implemented promises.

The functions uploadFiles() and addRecord() works completely fine seperately. But I want to run the functions together in onSubmit() function. The problem I'm facing is that addRecord() runs before the uploadFiles() completes its execution.

I have tried promises and async await to control the flow but unsuccessfull. I'm new to handling promises and stuck at it.

here's the uploadFiles code

```
const uploadFiles = (data) => {
const promises = [];
data.images.map((file) => {
  console.log("loop");

  const sotrageRef = ref(storage, `files/${file.name}`);

  const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(sotrageRef, file);
  promises.push(uploadTask);
  uploadTask.on(
    "state_changed",
    (snapshot) => {
      const prog = Math.round(
        (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
      );
      setProgress(prog);
    },
    (error) => console.log(error),
    async () => {
      await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURLs) => {
        setUrls((prevState) => [...prevState, downloadURLs]);
        console.log("File available at", downloadURLs);
      });
    }
  );
});
Promise.all(promises)
  .then(() => alert("All images uploaded"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

here's the onSubmit function

```
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
console.log("before upload");
await uploadFiles(data);
console.log("after upload");
console.log(urls);
await addRecord({
  title: data.title,
  eventType: data.eventType,
  date: data.date,
  venue: data.venue,
  description: data.description,
  details: data.details,
  images: urls,
  link: data.link,
  scheduleType: data.scheduleType,
    });
  };
```

The upload files sets the state of the urls to the image urls from the firebase storage. I have console logged messages before and after the uploadFiles. The `console.log(urls)` returns an empty array after the uploadFiles is completed, but the values are being populated with urls after the `addRecord` is being executed. This is resulting the firestore record to be an empty array for images.

Here's a screenshot of the console

[image]

Is anything wrong with the way I'm handling promises and async await.

Comment: `uploadFiles` needs to return a promise for `await uploadFiles(...)` to work as you expect. Add a return statement before `Promise.all`. Instead of `then` and `catch` blocks, just return the return of `return Promise.all(...)`

Comment: @Yousaf I have tried with the return statement. But this still return an empty array for `urls`

Comment: Is `uploadFiles` still not executing before `addRecord`?

Comment: It does execute before `addRecord` but the array is empty. It gets populated after a while, but by then the `addRecord` executes with empty array. Is it something I need to refactor with the firebase `uploadImage` logic?